# How to get notification when app closed?

Tags: ios, push-notification, signalr, appdelegate

I'm using SignalR for my app notification, when app running on background mode, my app got notification, but when I close my app I can't get notification. How can I get notification when I close app ?

Thanking you for answer me in advance :

Please find the below my sample code for more information:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification{


NSLog(@"notifi  %@ , %@",notification.alertBody,notification.alertTitle);
UIApplicationState state = [application applicationState];
if (state == UIApplicationStateActive) {
    UIAlertController * alert=   [UIAlertController
                                  alertControllerWithTitle:@"Title"
                                  message:@"Message"
                                  preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

    UIAlertAction* yesButton = [UIAlertAction
                                actionWithTitle:@"Yes, please"
                                style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                handler:^(UIAlertAction * action)
                                {
                                    //Handel your yes please button action here


                                }];
    UIAlertAction* noButton = [UIAlertAction
                               actionWithTitle:@"No, thanks"
                               style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                               handler:^(UIAlertAction * action)
                               {
                                   //Handel no, thanks button

                               }];

    [alert addAction:yesButton];
    [alert addAction:noButton];

    [self.window.rootViewController presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
}

// Request to reload table view data

// Set icon badge number to zero
application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;

 }
```

Comment: if (state == UIApplicationStateActive)  ? Your if only works when app is active... remove this ?

Comment: check in your notification payload, you are receiving title or alert key.